# LinkedList Error

Tags: java, linked-list, stack

Code "new Mystack<>();" is red underlined and I've the compiler Error: 
"*No enclosing instance of type LinkedListStack is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type LinkedListStack (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of LinkedListStack).*"

But I don't understand the message, whats wrong?

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class LinkedListStack {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyStack<Integer> stack = new MyStack<>();
    }


    class MyStack<E extends Number>
    {
        private LinkedList<E> elements = new LinkedList<>();

        public void push(E item) {
            elements.add(item);
        }

        public E pop() {
            return elements.removeFirst();
        }

        public E peek() {
            return elements.getLast();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You defined `MyStack` as an inner class of `LinkedListStack`, which means it requires an enclosing instance (of `LinkedListStack` class) to be instantiated:

```
MyStack<Integer> stack = new LinkedListStack().new MyStack<>();
```

Or you can change `MyStack` to a nested class, which doesn't require an enclosing instance:

```
static class MyStack<E extends Number>
{
    ...
}
```

This way you won't need to change your `main`.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring a nested class, which is bound to the enclosing class and therefore needs an instance of said class:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Add the keyword `static` to your definition of `MyStack`